# Django Multiple Nested inline formsets

Tags: django, django-forms

Is this even possible?

I need to store some documents to be retrieved as json/rest.

A `Document` has many `Sections`, and a section has a heading, a body and many `Images`.

Is there a way I can make a form with this structure?

```
Publication
|-- Section
    |-- Image
    |-- Image
|-- Section
    |-- Image
|-- Section
    |-- Image
    |-- Image
    |-- Image
```

My models:

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class Section(models.Model):
    publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication)
    heading = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    body = models.TextField()

class Image(models.Model):
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    alt_text = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

I can do this relatively easy when `Image` is related to `Publication`, because there is only one level of nesting.

When `Image` is belongs to `Section`, though, I'm not sure how to build the form.
It seems as though there's no easy way to do this with inline formsets.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6):

This can't be done in vanilla Django. I use [django-nested-inlines](https://github.com/Soaa-/django-nested-inlines) for this and it works really well.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from nested_inlines.admin import NestedModelAdmin, NestedTabularInline

from my.models import Publication, Section, Image


class ImageInline(NestedTabularInline):
    model = Image


class SectionInline(NestedTabularInline):
    model = Section
    inlines = [ImageInline,]


class PublicationAdmin(NestedModelAdmin):
    inlines = [SectionInline,]


admin.site.register(Publication, PublicationAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks, hellsgate. I'll check into it. My other option may be to make an `Image` library which is separate from the `Section`s. And then use a Javascript routine to associate the `Image`s.

Comment: I've added a simple code example for how it would work with the nested inlines. Good luck either way

Comment: I think I looked at django-nested-inlines last week. The thing is, I plan to make my own form for this, rather than django-admin.

Comment: Of course, django-nested-inlines is specific to admin so it would need some customisation for use outwith that. It would probably be worthwhile having a look inside the code to work out how it goes about it though, specifically the forms.py.

Comment: I'm investigating this: http://yergler.net/blog/2013/09/03/nested-formsets-redux/