# How to show list of foreign keys in Django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm creating a quiz app for my project. Each **quiz** can have multiple **questions** and each **question** has multiple **answers** from which one is correct.

The problem is that Django doesn't allow `OneToMany` relationship so I have to use `ForeignKey` in models.

```
class Language_Quiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    language = models.OneToOneField(sfl_models.Language)


class Question(models.Model):
    language_quiz = models.ForeignKey(Language_Quiz)
    text = models.TextField()

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='answers')
    text = models.TextField()
    correct = models.BooleanField()
```

What I want to do is - Django admin would show list of **Questions** assigned to current **Quiz** with ability to add or modify them so admin can add questions while creating a **Quiz**.

Could you give me a hint? It should be something with `admin.py`

Answer (score -1):

`ForeignKey` is the right field type. A `OneToMany` is only a reverse `ManyToOne` relation (which is a foreign key).

You can use [`InlineModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) to edit a `Quiz` and its `Question`s on the same form.

Editing `Answer`s on the same page would involve nested inline formsets, which is, AFAIK, not part of Django. If you want to achieve this, you might be interested in the following questions:

- [Django Multiple Nested inline formsets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18828944/1529346)
- [Django Nested Inline Formsets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20894629/1529346)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't probably support Django <= 1.8. I've posted a question about the error here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291894/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-commit-on-success