# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'commit_on_success'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm trying to use `Django-nested-inlines` application but it raises error. Here is a simple code:

**MODELS.PY**

```
class Language_Quiz(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    language = models.OneToOneField(sfl_models.Language)


class Question(models.Model):
    language_quiz = models.ForeignKey(Language_Quiz)
    text = models.TextField()

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question,related_name='answers')
    text = models.TextField()
    correct = models.BooleanField()
```

**ADMIN.PY**

```
from django.contrib import admin
import models
from nested_inlines.admin import NestedModelAdmin, NestedTabularInline

class AnswerInline(NestedTabularInline):
    model = models.Answer

class QuestionInline(NestedTabularInline):
    model = models.Question

class LanguageQuizAdmin(NestedModelAdmin):
    inlines = [QuestionInline]



admin.site.register(models.Language_Quiz,LanguageQuizAdmin)
admin.site.register(models.Answer)
admin.site.register(models.Question)
```

But when I run server or try to make migrations, the error is raised. I have no idea where is the problem. Where is the problem?

**TRACEBACK**

```
(venv) C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2>python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 328, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 22, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 24, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 74, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "c:\python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\language_tests\admin.py", line 3, in <module>
    from nested_inlines.admin import NestedModelAdmin, NestedTabularInline
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\nested_inlines\admin.py", line 16, in <module>
    class NestedModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
  File "C:\Users\Milano\PycharmProjects\FutileStudio\SolutionsForLanguages_2\venv\lib\site-packages\nested_inlines\admin.py", line 131, in NestedModelAdmin
    @transaction.commit_on_success
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'commit_on_success'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is "transaction.atomic" same as "transaction.commit\_on\_success"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861207/is-transaction-atomic-same-as-transaction-commit-on-success)

Comment: I think its the version compatibility issue. Which django version are you using. Does "Django-nested-inlines" supports that? Because _@transaction.atomic_ is now used inspite of _@transaction.commit_on_success_. If [this] could help (https://github.com/theatlantic/django-nested-admin/issues/7)

Comment: Dont use this library. The last modification was in 2013, and it looks like it is not being maintained anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kapil Sachdev and karthikr commented, the problem is with compatibility. **Django-nested-inlines** has probably some issues working with Django 1.8+.

In my case, the solution was very simple. Download using `pip` `Django-nested-inline` (without 's' at the end of the 'inline') and just change import. I didn't even have to change the code.