# Add logic in admin panel in Django

Tags: python, django

I have two models, the second model is `FK` from my first model like this:

```
class Model0(models.Model):
    work = models.FloatField(blank=True, null = True)

class Model1(models.Model):
    class Meta:
    unique_together = (('lat', 'lng'),)
    lng = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    lat = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

class Model2(models.Model):
    idWork    = models.ForeignKey('Model0', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    idSTFolio = models.OneToOneField('Model1', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I use admin panel to add my data, I need that when I add a second (Model0, Model1) with others values to Model1, in my Model2 this association was created automatically like this:

for example:

Model2 : (Model0, Model1)

`Id 1    : (1.5, (2.5, 3.0))`, 1.5 is 'Work' from Model0 and (2.5, 3.0) lat and lng in Model1

I need something like this...in this moment I create other Model1 with these values (2.5, 4.0), so like `lat: 2.5` has already been added in Model2 I need that in my Model2 add other row like this **automatically** :

`Id 1   : (1.5, (2.5, 3.0))
 Id 2   : (1.5, (2.5, 4.0))`

Any idea if it is possible to modify the admin panel for what I need?
In this moment I must add this association in my Model2 page in admin panel, but It not is my idea.

Answer (score 0):

I just googled for multi-level `inlines` and found [django-nested-inline package](https://github.com/s-block/django-nested-inline).

It seems promising to me for your purpose. I have found this in many stackoverflow answers as well:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/43719490/4772392
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18829259/4772392
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/26575394/4772392

I have never tried this package but I think, this will work for you.
Please let me know if it works for you.